# USAePay Create a payment method for a customer using the REST API and Sandbox not working - PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-method, usaepay

I got specified source key not found while creating a payment method, but i am able to collect the payment method. The issue only appears when I try to create a new one. All other endpoints work just fine. I am testing everything on the sandbox environment.

The base url will be
https://sandbox.usaepay.com/api/v2

and the full endpoint to create a payment method  for the customer will be a post request https://sandbox.usaepay.com/api/v2/customers/isddxhkfcwxq2663/payment_methods

```
API::setAuthentication('my_key','my_pin');

        info(API::ping());

        $request=[
            "custkey"=>"isddxhkfcwxq2663",
            "CustomerPaymentMethodRequests"=>[
                [
                    "expiration"=>"0924",
                    "number"=>"4000100011112224",
                    "pay_type"=>"cc",
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $response = Payment_methods::post($request);

        return $response;
```

I tried a post request to create a customers payment method and I am getting specified source key not found message